# enviar array con PHP MAILER

Tags: php, phpmailer

Hola como puedo enviar 3 arrays a través de PHP Mailer ya hace días que estoy tratando de hacerlo pero dentro de $mail->body no puedo poner FOR o FOREACH, ni un IF porque todo me da error. Adjunto mi código, los array vienen desde otro archivo php pero si simplemente los imprimo arriba de todo el código se imprimen perfecto, el tema esta que dentro de las comillas de $mail->body = '' no puede escribir prácticamente ninguna función de php. También se me ocurrió dividir el $mail-> body en 3 partes pero cuando lo hago el Email se envía pero totalmente en blanco

```
    <?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['active'])) {
    header("Location: ventas_todos.php");
}

if (!empty($nombres = $_REQUEST['list']) && !empty($precio = $_REQUEST['precio']) && !empty($cantidad = $_REQUEST['cantidad'])) {

    $nombres = $_REQUEST ['list'];
    $precio = $_REQUEST ['precio'];
    $cantidad = $_REQUEST ['cantidad'];


    require '../../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require '../../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require '../../vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        // Configuraciones del servidor
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Habilitar salida de depuración detallada
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Configurar el remitente para usar SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.alessi.com.ar';                  // Especificar servidores SMTP principales y de respaldo
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                             // Habilitar autenticación SMTP
        $mail->Username = 'info@alessi.com.ar';            // Nombre de usuario SMTP
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxxx';                   // Contraseña SMTP
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                       // Habilitar enciptación SSL, TLS también aceptado con el puerto 587
        $mail->Port = 465;                              // Puerto TCP para conectarse
        $mail->CharSet = "utf-8";
//Destinatarios
        $mail->setFrom("{$_SESSION ['email']}", "{$_SESSION ['empresa']}");
        $mail->addAddress('info@alessi.com.ar');     // Agregar un destinatario
//Contenido
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Establecer formato de correo electrónico a HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'PEDIDO MAYORISTA';

        $mail->Body = '
<html> 

<body> 

<h3>PEDIDO MAYORISTA</h3>

<p><b>USUARIO: </b>' . $_SESSION ['empresa'] . '</p>
    
<p><b>EMAIL: </b>' . $_SESSION ['email'] . '</p>

<table class="table table-bordered col-6" id="miTabla" style="border: 1px solid">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="bg-info text-center">
                        <th scope="col">PRODUCTO</th>
                        <th scope="col">PRECIO</th>
                        <th scope="col">CANTIDAD</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        <tr>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </body>
            </html>';

        if ($mail->send()) {
            echo 'exitos al enviar';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Deberías colocar el error que te muestra cuando haces foreach. Estás seguro que estás recorriendo el array correcto ?

Comment: Psdt: Deberías borrar la contraseña del email que haz puesto, alguien  podría hacer uso de esa cuenta..

Comment: no me sale ningun erro solo se envia el email pero en blanco, gracias por el aviso

Comment: intenta colocar el `isHTML` debajo del body y también prueba ingresando otro destinatario que sea diferente al que usas para enviar el correo

Answer (score -2, accepted):

puedes utilizar la funcion implode para convertir el array a a string

Comment: de casualidad has manejado selects con jquery mysql y php?

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo utilizaría `implode`?

Comment: has intentado enviar los nombres entre comillas simples separados por coma? me refiero que lo que quieres enviar son las variables nombre precio y cantidad?

Comment: si es asi intenta enviarlo colocandolos asi '$nombres', '$precio', '$cantidad';

Comment: cuando hago esto asi '$nombres', '$precio', '$cantidad en el email llega 1, 1, 1

Comment: como ven estoy tratando de crear una tabla para que lo reciba la persona en el email pero no se como mostra la tabla como corresponde un producto apilado sobre otro

Comment: Andres Canizales te daría un beso!!! el implode me solucionó todo, no lo conocia!!